# AWS S3 behaviour - Localhost v/s Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I built a web app and tested locally, everything seems to be working fine. Then, I tried deploying the app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. This is when I started encountering the below behaviour -

1. After a fresh deploy, I am able to open the landing page once.
2. When I try to navigate away from the landing page, I consistently get a `504 Bad Gateway` error.
3. I am unable to open the landing page without a fresh deploy, ie, I start getting the 504 error on the landing page as well.

I've been struggling with this for a while, and my best guess about the root cause is that it has something to do with a `HeadObjectCommand` + `GetObjectCommand` call my app makes to AWS S3 when I try to navigate to other pages. In my EB logs, I can see that these calls seem to be returning a `403 Forbidden` error. This is strange because I have set the Environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk and re checked them about 10 times. These calls are working completely smoothly when I test the app in my local environment.

Moreover, I'm unsure why I'm unable to even open the landing page once I get the 403 error on other pages.

I'm stumped on how to investigate this further and what I can do to get this working.

What am I missing? How can I figure out what's wrong and work to fix it? I'll be happy to promptly provide any more details that might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

[This article from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-s3-bucket-instance/) had the answer I was looking for.

Essentially, my mistake was in thinking that my app would access AWS S3 via an IAM user I had created and given AdministratorAccess to. Instead, Elastic Beanstalk has its own IAM profiles which need to be given the necessary permissions depending on your Bucket/Object policies before they can access those files. From what I gather, this process doesn't use my created IAM user profile at all. Oh well.